# How does one set value in header equal to current page group when pagebreaking after each group?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, rdl

How does one set a text value in header equal to the value of the current page group when pagebreaking after each group?

I'm not sure how else to elaborate. Can this be done?

Basically, I want to display some letterhead information in the header of the report- but, this information should pertain only to the group that is displayed on each page. The groups are never on the same report page, as I am pagebreaking after each group.

Are dynamic "Group" headers possible in SSRS 2016? Any potential solutions/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, as long as you have the content you wish to display somewhere in the body (even) hidden then you can reference it using ReportItems!MyTextBoxName.Value in the same way you would with a normal dataset field.

Comment: I have tried that. Unfortunately, it picks up the value of the 1st group of the 1st page of the report- and repeats that value on all header pages. (thanks for the suggest regardless! ..there MUST be a way... know/no?)

Comment: Did you include the scope? =(ReportItems!MyTextBoxName.Value, "myGroupName") ?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you much, sir. That worked perfect- exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. I'll move the comment to an answer so it can be marked as answered and closed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, as long as you have the content you wish to display somewhere in the body (even) hidden then you can reference it using ReportItems!MyTextBoxName.Value in the same way you would with a normal dataset field.

Include the scope to determine when the value changes.

```
=(ReportItems!MyTextBoxName.Value, "myGroupName")
```